# creating a sequential order of subprocess calls

Tags: python, subprocess

I am calling 5 scripts through subprocess function but I want to make sure that it processes it in the same order as in the script to ensure dependencies. Is there a quick way of combining these 5 subprocess functions in a sequential way?

```
# CONNECT DATABASE
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
from platform import python_version
import sys
import os
import subprocess
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import sqlite3
# connection to database
db = sqlite3.connect('gencodb.db')
# cursor
cursor = db.cursor()

# ENTER THE DATA WEEKS
run_date = '29/02/2020'
this_wk = '29FEB20'
last_wk = '22FEB20'
prev_wk = '15FEB20'

subprocess.call("python 01_DataCleaning_Transactions.py".split() +
                [run_date, this_wk, last_wk, prev_wk], shell=True)

subprocess.call("python 02_DataCleaning_Views.py".split() +
                [run_date, this_wk, last_wk, prev_wk], shell=True)

subprocess.call("python 03_DataCleaning_SP.py".split() +
                [run_date, this_wk, last_wk, prev_wk], shell=True)

subprocess.call("python 04_DataCleaning_Inventory.py".split() +
                [run_date, this_wk, last_wk, prev_wk], shell=True)

subprocess.call("python 05_DataCleaning_QAs.py".split() +
                [run_date, this_wk, last_wk, prev_wk], shell=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Instead of using `subprocess.call` you should use `subprocess.run` function it waits for the process to finish and returns the `CompletedProcess`**

**Note:**

### `subprocess.run(args)`

> Run the command described by args. Wait for command to complete, then
>   return a `CompletedProcess` instance.

You can refer more at [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run)

Comment: thanks for the answer, just to understand the syntax better I have a question. should I simply just change the "call"s in each block to "run" such as in the below example?               
          subprocess.run("python 01_DataCleaning_Transactions.py".split() +
                [run_date, this_wk, last_wk, prev_wk], shell=True)

Comment: @CagdasKanar Yep, you can do that.